Url Launcher stratagy flutter web
i develope app using flutter and used url_launcher and for routing used go_router.
while developing app and open url then it's work fine, but when build and upload to my server then it's not working both url_launcher and go_router.
i means when. i launch any url after upload server it's open with my server name
ex: if i open my social media account using url then
www.example.com/www.instagram.com/myinstaid

and when i hit direct url
www.example.com/dsc

then it's show this page not found.
i hope you understand , so please help me about this.
here is code for url launcher
 final Uri weburl = Uri(
  scheme: 'https',
  path: url,
  );
try {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(weburl)) {
    await launchUrl(
        weburl,
        mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView
    );
  }
}on PlatformException catch (e) {
  debugPrint("PlatformException launchInBrowser : $e");
} on Exception catch (e) {
  debugPrint( "Exception launchInBrowser : $e");
}

go router code:
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(


initialLocation: '/',
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: URL_HOME,
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        GoRoute(
          path: URL_DSC,
          name: URL_DSC,
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const DSCCertificate();
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
            path: URL_APPLY_DSC,
            name: URL_APPLY_DSC,
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ApplyDSCScreen();
            }),
        GoRoute(
          path: URL_MSME,
          name: URL_MSME,
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const MSMEUdyamScreen();
          },
        ),

    GoRoute(
        path: URL_FASTAG,
        name: URL_FASTAG,
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const FastagScreen();
        }),
  ],
),


],
);

thank you :)

Add some code so we can figure out the error. Codes of pages like main.dart, call of the url you mentioned, etc would be helpful.

@ClevinoAlrin i added my code. and you can also check url in code directy

Did you get any error message in the console?

For insta url, you don’t  need to add your server url. As for your page dsc make sure its the right path ... Can you share what value URL_DSC holds?

@ClevinoAlrin full url is www.example.com/dsc
URL_DSC value is just dsc
while navigating it's worked, but whenever i launch on website and then hit direct above url then its show me page not found, navigation worked but direct link not work, hope you understand

Are you trying to open your app AND other urls in inAppWebView ?

i found the problem is getting use when usePathUrlStrategy(); in main() , use because remove # but when i remove this usePathUrlStrategy(); then # present in url

finally i resolve this stuff after long days
firstly
Add the url_strategy package to my pubspec.yaml dependencies.
In my main.dart file, import the package and call setPathUrlStrategy() before running my app:
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  setPathUrlStrategy(); // This removes the hash from the URL
  runApp(MyApp());
}

i put this code in .htaccess file.(if not exist you can create it) my server main public_html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

this will help me to open deep link url and if i want to open any other domain i just use below code.
import html
import 'dart:html' as html;
and used it
html.window.open('https://www.facebook.com/burhanisolution', 'new tab');

